# Onstop method is called when Orientation changes

Tags: android

When I change the orientation of the Android application, it calls onStop method and then onCreate. How to avoid caling onStop and onCreate when orientation changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It have been long time since this question have been active, but I sill need to answer this. I had same issue and found answer.

In manifest you should add `android:configChanges=orientation|screenLayout|layoutDirection|screenSize` in your activity which should not call default actions on orientation change.

```
...
<activity android:name=".Activity"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|layoutDirection|screenSize" 
...
```

And in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // This overrides default action
}
```

Original example:
http://android-er.blogspot.fi/2011/05/prevent-activity-restart-when-screen.html

Comment: I had to add "|screenSize" as well for more recent OSs.

Comment: Yes, basically add any parameter that might be related to or caused by orientation change.

Comment: Edited answer so that "screenSize" is in parameter list as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior: the activity is recreated when orientation changes. But you can decide to ignore this event. You can find details here : [How to make an application ignore screen orientation change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410504/android-how-to-make-application-completely-ignore-screen-orientation-change)

Comment: Well, the technique in the linked article apparently prevents orientation changes, but not the calls to the callbacks when the orientation changes (which is what was asked).

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid that, those are system callbacks.
You can save the state though in onStop and then have the system pass it to onCreate for a faster recovery of the state after the screen orientation has changed.

See also [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html) and [that](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) article on the developer pages.

Comment: This can avoided by calling android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  . But still there are some issues

Comment: Well, this apparently prevents orientation changes, but not the calls to the callbacks when the orientation changes (which is what was asked).