# Receiving a broadcast during Activity's lifecycle changes

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

Let's say I have an `Activity`. In its `onCreate` lifecycle callback I create a `BroadcastReceiver` object by implementing it as an anonymous class and put some code inside its `onReceive` callback that requires `Activity`'s `Context` to show a `Toast` message when it gets called. In `Activity`'s `onResume` callback I register that `BroadcastReceiver` and in `onPause` I unregister it, because it contains code that requires `Activity`'s `Context`, and it might not be available if `Activity` is going through the destruction procedure, i.e. orientation change. This means that if something, i.e. `IntentService` broadcasts an `Intent` for that `BroadcastReceiver` while it's unregistered (no matter how short, but it still can happen), the `Intent` will never get delivered and proper actions that handle it will never happen. So the user might miss some important information (message informing about a succesfull registration, warning that something went wrong etc.) Am I right? Is it true that such scenario may happen? How to prevent it? How to make sure that the `BroadcastReceiver` will receive the broadcast no matter when some part of the application fires it?

Comment: do not use `BroadcastReceiver` in such case, use a "bound service" pattern instead

Comment: I've totally forgotten about a thing like that. Haven't been developing for Android for quite a while :(. I'll think of a solution using the bound service, but I'd still appreciate getting some simpler solution advice.

Answer (score 1):

Create `MyBroadcastReceiver` extending `BroadcastReceiver` (of course :D) and register that in the manifest with the appropriate intent filter action. Then in `onReceive()` you'll have access to `Application's Context`. Keep in mind that `onReceive()` will be triggered even if your app is closed (if your action is `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` for example).
It depends on what you're trying to do in that receiver...also have a look at EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus if you have to send events in your app.

Comment: In that `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive` I just want to show a message for a user, but that message may be shown in a form of a `TextView`, but without `Activity`'s `Context` reaching that `TextView` is meaningless :).

Comment: Ok, who sends the message? If I get this right, you want to push the messages inside a queue when they arrive and when the `Activity` opens, show those messages? You may want to consider saving those messages...I don't think I understand why would you want to show the messages when the activity isn't open.

Comment: You understood me wrong. I just want to let the `Activity` know when i.e. some `Service` finishes its work. If the `Activity` is destroyed because user wished so, then the message shouldn't be displayed, but I'm afraid this can happen on an orientation change for example. That way the `Activity` may not receive the message making the user to wait for a message that have already been sent and will never be again.

Comment: Oh ok! In this case you may want to override `onConfigurationChanged()` this allows you to set the landscape layout without restarting the `Activity`.
Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961054/onstop-method-is-called-when-orientation-changes

Comment: I'm looking for a simpler solution man :D. Reinventing all the orientation change logic just to make sure a message from `Service` is shown is not worth it :D. I think I'll consider risking that message will not get shown or implementing the bound service pattern if I decide that message is of such a great importance. But thanks for wonderful advices!

Comment: By the way, I liked the idea about saving messages somewhere and displaying them when `Activity` starts. Will definitely use it somewhere in near future!

Comment: @Salivan `"... I liked the idea about saving messages somewhere and displaying them when Activity starts."` you save it in a Service and ask for a data when Activity binds to a Service, read about `"local bound service"` pattern [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder)