# Android video not starting if phone is already in Landscape mode

Tags: android, video, orientation

I have an Activity that uses a VideoView to play a video file.
The onCreate method sets the orientation to Landscape, and then loads the video and plays it.

This video activity is called from my main activity. The main activity is set to portrait orientation in the manifest.

This all works great when the phone is held vertically.
 - Main Activity starts in portrait
 - Click button to launch video activity
 - Video activity launches in landscape
 - Video plays

However, if the phone is help horizontally, the video does not start playing:
 - Main Activity starts in portrait
 - Click button to launch video activity
 - Video activity launches in landscape
 - Video is loaded but is paused - have to manually start.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Video Activity Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.video_view);

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    mVideoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    String videoUrl = "/mnt/sdcard-ext" + "/Videos/Wildlife.wmv";
    playVideo(videoUrl);

    // video finish listener
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MyOnCompletionListener());
}

public void playVideo(String videoUrl)
{
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
    mVideoView.requestFocus(); 
    mVideoView.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting log messages inside your onCreate(). Maybe in your scenario Activity is created twice.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that can be used in portrait or landscape that involves random info. When I switch from portrait to landscape and vice versa new info is generated. This leads me to think

```
onCreate()
```

is called even when the phone rotates. (Verification?)

I don't see why calling it twice would pause the video, but perhaps tagging your Video Activity in the manifest also, this time for landscape,

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

would prevent it from calling twice.

Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be it... Tested that OnCreate is only called once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always call it in landscape , just put this info in manifest file .It will work perfectly

Comment: add this attribute  android:screenOrientation="landscape" to your activity in manifest file

Comment: I get the same behavior when the attribute is in the manifest as well :/

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410504/android-how-to-make-application-completely-ignore-screen-orientation-change , you might have to override that function @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}