# Can we ignore screen orientation or do we have to handle it?

Tags: iphone

Although I know how to handle **screen orientation** in an iPhone application. Is there possibly a way we can ignore it?

Either by means of some *code* or may be setting it somewhere. For example in *Android* we can [ignore screen orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410504/android-how-to-make-application-completely-ignore-screen-orientation-change) by making few changes. Is there some way in iPhone too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't implement or handle all the orientation then it should be oke:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

You app will only support portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

you can stop screen orientation by returning `interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` on `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation`

Edited to be technically correct.

Comment: Your answer is technically incorrect. @rckonenes has the right answer. You don't return orientation in shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation, you return a boolean.