# Samsung Galaxy Tab portrait orientation problems

Tags: android, tabs, orientation, portrait

I making an app and im currently optimizing it to Samsung Galaxy Tab.
I have a little problem here, when i launch the application, it is came up in only one portrait orientation.

I use this code:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

It is only working with one portrait screen orientation, so if i rotate the device to upside down, its now changing. 
Its a little annoying, because if i start the application in the wrong orientation, my app came up in upside down and wont change.

What can i do with this ?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410504/how-to-make-application-completely-ignore-screen-orientation-change-in-android

Comment: @papaiatis its not his issue actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Activity. setRequestedOrientation(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29)

The parameter can be either `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` or `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` ,
you should set **`android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"`** if you are on API Level 9+.

For more info: check [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen).

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate() before calling super.onCreate() call below method... it should work...

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```