# Button properties changes doesn't save after screen rotate

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I have a button which when pressed gets bigger and changes text color, but when the screen rotates, the button loses the new properties (size and text color). How can I make it save?
Here's the code for the button

```
public void changeColor(View view) {
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
    button2.setTextSize(50);
}
```

in the button XML I have given it ID, and onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `manifest.xml` write

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

**Example**

```
<activity
      android:name=".MainAct"
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
</activity>
```

Comment: awesome thanks, though I don't even knew about this thing. Is this the standart way to set things not change when rotate?

Comment: but why keyboardhidden? most android phones are without keyboards, shouldn't it be something like screenorientation?

Comment: you can read this doc http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html and you can vote up too

Answer (score 0):

After the screen rotation  your app is started again new. So you can for example ignore screen rotation ([How to make an application ignore screen orientation change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410504/how-to-make-application-completely-ignore-screen-orientation-change-in-android)) or store your values after buton pressing in shared preferences and call them after screen rotation