# Android: Lock Screen-Rotation while ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, progressdialog, screen-rotation

in my app I get data while a ProgressDialog is shown.
Now I want to keep the current screen rotation (Landscape/Portrai) while the ProgressDialog is shown to prevent some errors. After the process is finished I want to "releace" the app and enable the screen rotation.

How do I do this?

Comment: better to get orientation before you start progressbar and set that in setoreientation method using if/else.

Comment: `keep the current screen rotation to prevent some errors` sounds  ridiculously ... better fix em in another way

Comment: @Selvin I create a "big" list and on some older phones, this needs some seconds and if they turn the device I get 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Answer (score 0):

Add the orientationChange to intercepted activity config changes (in the manifest), then override `onConfigurationChanged()` and simply call `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);` when your progress bar is running

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410504/how-to-make-application-completely-ignore-screen-orientation-change-in-android) answer: you'll only need to apply this behaviour when `yourprogressbar.isVisible()` is true